# Android Realm Google Maps Memory Leak

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, memory-leaks, realm

My main class application retrieves data using Retrofit and writes to a POJO ordinary Realm object. Then run the second Activity (MapsActivity) where I set the map, filter the contents of the Realm object for the relevant data. Everything works. 
I will add that the Realm object contains over 6600 rows so it is big. And unfortunately I feel I have leaks of memory. Each time you start MapsActivity (going back to MainActivity, selecting another category, and passing it to MapsActivity), the heap looks awful. This is shown in the attached image. I will add that the application works much better when I do not use the Realm object at all, I only do the second Retrofit call in the MapsActivity class. This solution unfortunately doubles my work (in Main and Maps I do exactly the same thing) and I want to avoid this. Maybe someone will see where I have a leak and why the program is slowing down.
[image: Heap]
My Main:
package com.flex.sklepik;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> shopsNames;
    ArrayList<RowModel> rowModels;
    public static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1972;

    public Realm mRealm;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar_layout)
    CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.app_bar)
    AppBarLayout appBar;
    private ShopsAdapter adapter;
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Dialog errorDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        startRegistrationService();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ConnectionDetector connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(this);
        if (!connectionDetector.isConnection()) {
            finish();
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);

        checkPlayServices();

        rowModels = new ArrayList<>();
        shopsNames = new ArrayList<>();
        Realm.init(this);

        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        initCollapsingToolbar();

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.shoplogo).
                into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));

        adapter = new ShopsAdapter(MainActivity.this, shopsNames);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        AsyncTaskRetro asyncTaskRetro = new AsyncTaskRetro();

        asyncTaskRetro.execute();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {

        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {

                if (errorDialog == null) {
                    errorDialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 2404);
                    errorDialog.setCancelable(false);
                }

                if (!errorDialog.isShowing())
                    errorDialog.show();
            }
        }

        return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    private class AsyncTaskRetro extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Czekaj...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.hide();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            PlacesAPI.Factory.getInstance().getPlaces().enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPosts().size(); i++) {
                        RowModel rowModel = new RowModel(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getNazwa(),
                                Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getSzer()),
                                Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getDlug()));
                        rowModels.add(rowModel);
                    }
                    String oldName;
                    oldName = rowModels.get(0).getName();
                    shopsNames.add(rowModels.get(0).getName());

                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    mRealm.copyToRealm(rowModels);
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();

                    for (int j = 0; j < rowModels.size(); j++) {

                        if (rowModels.get(j).getName().equals(oldName)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        oldName = rowModels.get(j).getName();
                        shopsNames.add(rowModels.get(j).getName());
                    }

                    //sortowanie listy z nazwami sklepow
                    Collections.sort(shopsNames);

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Places> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRegistrationService() {
        GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int code = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (code == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            onActivityResult(REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES, Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
        } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(code) &&
                api.showErrorDialogFragment(this, code, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES)) {
            // wait for onActivityResult call (see below)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, api.getErrorString(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                }
                break;

            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Map Class:

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
         {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private double naviLat, naviLong;
private double latitude, longitude;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@BindView(R.id.adView)
AdView adView;
@BindView(R.id.butnavi)
ImageButton butnavi;
private Location location;
private RealmResults<RowModel> rowModels;
private String shopName;
private Bundle bundle;
private Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map2);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);



    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    shopName = bundle.getString("shopName");

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Uprawnienia nie przyznane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    cameraMove();

    //po wczytaniu mapy wyciągnij dane z bazy sklepów
    realmDatabaseBuild();
}

private void addMarker(double lat, double lon) {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)));
}

@OnClick(R.id.butnavi)
public void btnNavi() {
    if (naviLat + naviLong == 0)
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Najpierw wybierz market", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                .parse("google.navigation:q=" + naviLat + ","
                        + naviLong));

        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private void moveCameraToActualPosition(double lat, double lon) {
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(lat, lon))
            .zoom(12).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}

private void realmDatabaseBuild() {

    rowModels = realm.where(RowModel.class).equalTo("name", shopName).findAll();
    if (!rowModels.isEmpty()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < rowModels.size(); i++) {

            addMarker(rowModels.get(i).getLongitude(), rowModels.get(i).getLattitude());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    mMap.clear();
    rowModels = null;
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    LatLng gps = marker.getPosition();

    //ustawienie lat i long dla nawigacji
    naviLat = gps.latitude;
    naviLong = gps.longitude;

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(gps.latitude, gps.longitude, 1);
        String adres = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Adres: " + adres, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}



public void cameraMove() {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Uprawnienia nie przyznane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (myLocation != null) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(ll)
                .zoom(11).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    } else {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(52.230625, 21.013129);//WAWA
        CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(ll)
                .zoom(10).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cp));
    }
}
```

}

And Pojo:

```
public class RowModel extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    private String name;
    @Required
    private Double lattitude, longitude;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getLattitude() {
        return lattitude;
    }

    public void setLattitude(Double lattitude) {
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public RowModel(String name, Double lattitude, Double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public RowModel() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not closing Realm therfore causing an excessive Memory leak on the main thread

Comment: in which code fragment?